# Error: require is not defined after upgrade angular2 to rc1

Tags: angular, require

after I upgraded the angular2 to latest rc1 I've started to have problem with the app. The current source code is on github: https://github.com/bkielbasa/form-front/tree/upgrade-angular
I tried many things but nothing helped.

I have noticed that when I add `alert('1');` in main.ts before first `import` the popup shows up, but when I add it just after the first `import` it does not show and I can see the error in my console.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Please add your source code or error that you faced it would be more helpful to figure out the problem

Comment: I added the code here: https://github.com/bkielbasa/form-front/tree/upgrade-angular

Comment: yeah saw in question, i was talkin about error you faced.

Comment: I added it too, it was `Error: require is not defined` in my console. Here is an example: http://form-frontend-dev.epicsoft.pl/

Comment: try using `systemJs` as module under compilerOptions in the `tsconfig.json` file.

Comment: U need to update your index.html to include es6 shim, reflect metadata, zome and system libs. Then map @angular and provide config to System. I faced similar issue while upgrading to RC. Getting started of angular.io will give you the above info in details

Comment: Onr more thing, u need to remove system js and angular polyfills